# Improving the speed and efficiency of this PHP spellchecker

Tags: php, string, spell-checking

I built a simple PHP spellchecker and suggestions application that uses PHP's similar_text() and levenshtein() functions to compare words from a dictionary that is loaded into an array.

- How it works: First I load the contents of the dictionary into an
  array.
- I split the user's input into words and spell check each of the
  words.
- I spell check by checking if the word is in the array that is the
  dictionary.
- If it is, then I echo a congratulations message and move on.
- If not, I iterate through the dictionary-array comparing each word, in the dictionary-array, with the assumed misspelling.
- If the inputted word, in lower-case and without punctuation, is 90%
  or more similar to a word in the dictionary array, then I copy that
  word from the dictionary array into an array of suggestions.
- If no suggestions were found using the 90% or higher similarity
  comparison, then I use levenshtein() to do a more liberal comparison
  and add suggestions to the suggestions array.
- Then I iterate through the suggestions array and echo each
  suggestion.

I noticed that this is running slowly. Slow enough to notice. And I was wondering how I could improve the speed and efficiency of this spell checker.

Any and all changes, improvements, suggestions, and code are welcome and appreciated.

Here is the code (for syntax highlighted code, please [visit here](http://pastebin.com/sjR2p41w)):

```
<?php
    function addTo($line) {
        return strtolower(trim($line));
    }

    $words = array_map('addTo', file('dictionary.txt'));
    $words = array_unique($words);

    function checkSpelling($input, $words) {
        $suggestions = array();
        if (in_array($input, $words)) {
            echo "you spelled the word right!";
        }
        else {
            foreach($words as $word) {
                $percentageSimilarity = 0.0;
                $input = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i', '', $input);
                similar_text(strtolower(trim($input)), strtolower(trim($word)), $percentageSimilarity);
                if ($percentageSimilarity >= 90 && $percentageSimilarity<100) {
                    if(!in_array($suggestions)){
                        array_push($suggestions, $word);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (empty($suggestions)) {
                foreach($words as $word) {
                    $input = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i', '', $input);
                    $levenshtein = levenshtein(strtolower(trim($input)), strtolower(trim($word)));
                    if ($levenshtein <= 2 && $levenshtein>0) {
                        if(!in_array($suggestions)) {
                            array_push($suggestions, $word);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "Looks like you spelled that wrong. Here are some suggestions: <br />";
            foreach($suggestions as $suggestion) {
                echo "<br />".$suggestion."<br />";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_GET['check'])) {
        $input = trim($_GET['check']);
        $sentence = '';
        if (stripos($input, ' ') !== false) {
            $sentence = explode(' ', $input);
            foreach($sentence as $item){
                checkSpelling($item, $words);
            }
        }
        else {
            checkSpelling($input, $words);
        }
    }

?>

<!Doctype HTMl>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Spell Check</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
             <input type="text" name="check" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using an extension like [Enchant](http://php.net/enchant) or [Pspell](http://php.net/pspell)? They have `suggest` functions that basically do what you are trying to do.

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen PSell is not supported in 5.3

Comment: @JayGatz I know, but Enchant is supported.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It is? In the documentation it says it requires plugins.

Comment: @JayGatz It is an extension, so yes, it needs to be installed and enabled.

Comment: Will that result in valid HTML? Shouldn't (most of) the PHP code be within the `body` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein over a large list will be pretty processor intensive. Right now if you mistyped refridgerator it would calculate the edit distance to cat dog and pimple.

Too pare the list down before going into the levenstein loop you could match against a precalculated metaphone or soundex key for each of your dictionary entries. This would give you a much shorter list of likely suggestions then you could use levenshtein and similar_text as a means of rank the short list of matches.

Another thing that may help you out is to cache your results. I would venture to guess that most of the misspellings are going to be common.

The following implementation doesn't deal with the paring of the data effectively but it should give you some guidelines on how to dodge the levenshtein distance against the entire dictionary for each word.

First thing you are going to want to do is append the metaphone results to each of your word entries.
This would be a servicable way to do that

```
<?php
$dict = fopen("dictionary-orig.txt", "r");
$keyedDict = fopen("dictionary.txt", "w");
while ($line = fgets($dict)){
    $line = trim(strtolower($line));
    fputcsv($keyedDict, array($line,metaphone($line)));
}
fclose($dict);
fclose($keyedDict);
?>
```

Along with this you are going to need something that can read the dictionary into an array

```
<?php
function readDictionary($file){
        $dict = fopen($file, "r");
        $words = array();
        while($line = fgetcsv($dict)){
                $words[$line[0]] = $line[1];
        }
        return $words;
}
function checkSpelling($input, $words){
    if(array_key_exists($input, $words)){

        return;
    }
        else {
        // sanatize the input
        $input = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i', '', $input);
        // get the metaphone key for the input
        $inputkey = metaphone($input);
        echo $inputkey."<br/>";
        $suggestions = array();
        foreach($words as $word => $key){
            // get the similarity between the keys
            $percentageSimilarity = 0;
            similar_text($key, $inputkey, $percentageSimilarity);
            if($percentageSimilarity > 90){
                $suggestions[] = array($word, levenshtein($input, $word));
            }
        }
        // rank the suggestions
        usort($suggestions, "rankSuggestions");
        return $suggestions;
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['check'])){
    $words = readDictionary("dictionary.txt");
    $input = trim($_GET['check']);
    $sentence='';
    $sentence = explode(' ', $input);
    print "Searching Words ".implode(",", $sentence);
    foreach($sentence as $item){
        $suggestionsArray = checkSpelling($item, $words);
        if (is_array($suggestionsArray)){
                echo $item, " not found, maybe you meant";
                var_dump($suggestionsArray);
        } else {
                echo "found $item";
        }
    }
}
function rankSuggestions($a, $b){
        return $a[1]-$b[1];
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Spell Check</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="get">
             <input type="text" name="check" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
        </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The simplest way to do actual paring of the data would be to split your dictionary into multiple files partitioned by something like the first character in the string. Something along the lines for dict.a.txt, dict.b.txt, dict.c.txt etc.

Comment: Yes, it would do a comparison between cat, dog, and pimple. Ah, okay. Good idea.

Comment: Could you update your answer with how to use `metaphone()` or `soundex()` to create a smaller array and then do the levenshtein comparison between what is in the samller array and the $input ? I have some trouble understanding the output of the metaphone and soundex functions and how I can know what type of output means the words are close in comparison. For similar_text it is a simple percentage.

Comment: If you are willing to help me out with an implementation using soundex() or metaphone could you let me know? Could you please also let me know if you are not willing to give anymore help in your answer?

Comment: sorry afk for the day. will form an example in a few hours

Comment: @jayGatz Updated the answer, code is untested but should steer you in the right direction

Comment: I seemed to understand where you were going with it. But I slightly further developed your code to test it and now not even the HTML is rendering? Also how do I load the new dictionary that is made by the first part of your code. Right now, on line 11, I am loading the only dictionary. Here is the code if you don't mind taking a look at it: http://pastebin.com/g61A1cww

Comment: updated the code this has been tested. One thing I don't think you got was that the first code snippet should be run once to build a new dictionary off of your first. You should not do this for every request, only once and every time you update the dictionary. change the name of your dictionary.txt file to dictionary-orig.txt create a new php file named build-dictionary.php then hit it with the browser. Make sure that the web server can create the new dictionary.txt

Comment: Thank you. And Thank you for testing it. Ah, okay. So only update the dictionary once and on update. Not on each request. That makes sense. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I am getting an error in buildDicitonary.php, the first part of your code, on the line with `fputcsv()` that says expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given. [Here is the dictionary-orig.txt](http://the-irf.com/dictionary-orig.txt) that I am trying it with.

Comment: That probably means the web server does not have permission to create the dictionary.txt file. Change the permissions of the directory and try again.

Comment: 773 turned out to be the proper permissions, but now I am getting an HTTP 500 error in the second part of your code. Here is what the server log says: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in spellCheck/check.php on line 31` and line 31 is `usort($suggestions, function ($a, $b){`

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31489/discussion-between-orangepill-and-jaygatz)